# Is it really true that radios work better in mountaneous region than in cities?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electronics, antennas, radio

I was recently travelling somwhere with my family. During the journey we had to pass through a mountaneous terrain. My mother suddenly switched on the radio of car and it was so clear. Is this true that they work better in mountaneous region or it was just by chance? If yes can you please explain the reason for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is generally not true. For FM transmissions, mountains bounce away and thereby block the radio waves, making FM reception especially poor in the mountain valleys. However, if you are "in the clear" (at the top of a mountain), your FM reception will greatly improve if that summit furnishes a direct "line of sight" between your car and the distant antenna.

Note also that it is common to put FM transmitting antennas on top of mountains, to increase their effective range. Driving past one of these will furnish you with an extremely strong signal!

Answer (score 1):

Yes its better over mountains if you are at a suitable spot with fewer hills and clear environment.
Generally in towns and cities radio waves are obstructed by buildings and other things whereas in heights such as hill top you can get better radio transmission compared to residential areas.